# Shrinking SliverAppBar to only cover the status bar?

Tags: flutter, dart

When using the SliverAppBar, I want to have it shrink down to cover only the status bar text (time, battery life, signal strength).  The standard `collapsedHeight` seems to be around 60.0, if I try to shrink it to anything smaller then there are some horrible errors about it being smaller then the `toolBarHeight`.

So I went ahead and just shrunk the `toolBarHeight` down to 0.0 and then I am allowed to take `collapsedHeight` to 0.0 as well, and it gives the exact effect I was hoping for.  The sliver will successfully shrink down to only cover the status bar.

However, the problem with this, is that by making the `toolBarHeight` = 0, then the back button and `actions` icons are similarly shrunk down to 0, effectively disappeared.

Is there any way to keep the Icons such as back button and `action` icons maintain there height while setting the `toolBarHeight` = 0, or any other strategy to try to achieve what I would think would be a common arrangement?

```
return
      SliverAppBar(
          expandedHeight: 80.0,
          collapsedHeight: 0.0,
          toolbarHeight: 0.0,
          stretch: false,
          floating: false,
          pinned: true,
          elevation: 0,
          automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
          forceElevated: true,
          shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
              bottom: Radius.circular(28),
            )),
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
           background:
              SafeArea(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(60,0,100,0),
                  child: MySliverTitle(
                    geaderText:'Testing',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            MyIcon1(),MyIcon2()

          ]
      );
```